Effects of the SBC vote to expel church with women pastors
NPR has been reporting on this topic in the past few days1  and from my understanding this won't necessarily affect local congregations. Southern Baptist Convention website states:

Jesus Christ is the head of the local church—we are not. Each church is responsible before God for the policies it sets and decisions it makes.

or Article XIV

Such organizations have no authority over one another or over the churches. They are voluntary and advisory bodies designed to elicit, combine, and direct the energies of our people in the most effective manner.

My question is: Will this have any other side effects/impacts besides changing the constitution and having fewer congregations part of the convention? Will this affect SBC relationship with Woman’s Missionary Union?
The SBC FAQ also states

The Convention recognizes the biblical language concerning the office of pastor. The BF&M statement says, “While both men and women are gifted for service in the church, the office of pastor is limited to men as qualified by Scripture.” The passages that assign the office of pastor to men do not negate the essential equality of men and women before God, but rather focus on the assignment of roles.

making the whole topic is slightly confusing, i.e. is this vote to make this policy more official as part of the constitution and will there be fewer side effects then predicted?
Related:

What is the biblical justification for permitting female pastors?
In a congregationalist church, who is in charge and what does this imply for women in authoritative roles?

1 See this article (6/11/24), this article (6/12/24), this article (6/4/24)

According to the SBC missionaries are not considered pastors, so it is unlikely that there will be an effect on missionary organisations.

@DJClayworth I can't find anything necessarily hinting at it, but at the same time it sounds like this is a big change (could just be media being media) and I didn't know how this policy change might trickle down

There have been Baptist women missionaries for centuries, even when there was not the slightest consideration that women might be pastors. Women make up a big fraction of missionaries, even in SBC-afilliated churches. To kick out any church that allowed women to be missionaries would see a massive reduction in SBC membership, and a massive reduction in the number of missionaries sent out. The fact that women can be the sole teachers of an entire people (as missionaries) but can't lead a church back home is just one part of the wierdness that is this whole debate.
